# How to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH to all users and system services

Tags: environment-variables, path, libraries, dynamic-loading

I want to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to system services and all users.
System services are run before login, so `.bashrc` is not applicable.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 24):

You don't need to. Add the directory to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`, depending on distro.

After that, you must run (at least on Redhat) `ldconfig` as root.

As a word of caution, you need to be careful which libraries you add to the system shared library path (via the environment, ld.so.conf, or putting in /usr/local/lib). In particular, you beware of two different versions of the same library with the same soname. E.g., if you have a libfoo.0.1 (soname libfoo.0) installed via dpkg/rpm/etc., you don't want a libfoo.0.2 (also soname libfoo.0) in your custom library directory.

(It's actually not that easy to pull off a system-wide environment variable. You can get most user logins with `/etc/environment`. Scripts will depend on your init system, but (for example) with sysv init on Debian, you could put it in `/etc/default/rcS`. Anything run straight out of inittab, well, I don't think you can.)

Comment: @bahamat I'm guessing due to an edit overlap, you wound up taking out a paragraph from my answer. I'll add it back..

Comment: Nope, I just removed it because "you don't need to" already sums it up and it's much more concise.

Comment: @bahamat Check the edit log, http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/46620/revisions ... I think what happened is that we both hit the edit link, then I submitted my change (the extra paragraph), then you submitted your change (which of course didn't include the extra paragraph). Seems like StackExchange ought to detect this and warn loudly, but apparently not...

Comment: No, I just explicitly removed that paragraph because I thought it was unnecessary. I didn't make any other changes. Our edits were 6m apart and the one that came after me was 12m later. It wasn't a collision.

Comment: @bahamat Ah, leaving an edit comment would have cleared up the confusion...

Comment: But depending on what is actually in the target directory this could potentially cause a lot of problems.

Comment: @Keith that's true, though I think it'd be no more than would be caused by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH system-wide. I'll add in a word of caution.

Comment: This doesn't work. At all. LD_LIBRARY_PATH will still always be blank.

Comment: @DissidentRage That's the point, the environment variable doesn't need to be set to add a directory to the system library path.

Answer (score 3):

You can add every path in the file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` then run :

```
ldconfig -v
```

Then load them.